# Updated documentation for Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm looking for updated documentation on Nhibernate, particularly with the information regarding the upgrades in Nhibernate 4.0. The [official documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/) appears to only have information regarding Nhibernate 2.1.0, but according to the [wikipedia page for Nhibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate) there have been a few substantial changes to Nhibernate, most notably with the fact that you no longer need .hbm.xml files, something that is still a focal point to the original documentation. Any tutorials that are available about Nhibernate, particularly the [Summer of nhibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/) screencasts are based on the older versions.

Long story short, is there any updated documentation for Nhibernate that includes the updated material from 3.0 up to version 4.0?

Comment: Unfortunately I think the best documentation you'll find is the source code itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the documentation lacks the description of new features. For instance the mapping-by-code possibility is not explained anywhere. A description how to use mapping-by-code can be retrieved from this Blog:

http://notherdev.blogspot.de/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html